# What's the equivalent for pred and succ in C#?

Tags: c#, pascal, equivalent

Pascal is my study language and I am curious whether *C#* also has the functions `pred` and `succ`.

*This is what I have done in Pascal that I want to try in C#*

```
// in Pascal:
pred(3) = 2
succ(False) = True
pred('b') = 'a'
type enum = (foo, bar, baz);
succ(bar) = baz; pred(bar) = foo
```

Is the same code applicable for C#, too? If so, what is the namespace for these functions?

(I searched Google, but couldn't find the answer)

Comment: This is an interesting question rather spoiled by the poor choice of example. The pred and succ operators do apply in Pascal to all ordinal types but they are not interesting for integers. They are almost exclusively used for enumerated types.

Comment: @David. Sorry that I could not meet up the needs to make this question an interesting one with a good example. If you are interested in the subject of pred and succ in pascal, I am happy to allow your changes on the program, as I believe every bit of code update is good for both of us. :D

Comment: Nowadays in Pascal derivatives (not sure if it is standard Pascal) one would write inc/dec as equivalent to ++/-- from C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't `pred` and `succ` functions in C#.  You just write `n - 1` or `n + 1`.

Comment: ouch. :(. Thanks for the information. I give a tick for you for a fast and good one .

Answer (score 2):

You have method overloading in c# so it's easy to have pred and succ, You can do it by:

```
public int pred(int input)
{
   return input - 1;
}

public char pred(char input)
{
  return (char)((int)input - 1);
}
....
```

Comment: Thanks for writing me a simple procedure for me to put in real time use. :D

Comment: @Marie Curie, I wroted this to clarify difference between `char` and `int` because it's not as simple as `int`

Comment: so you are trying to clarify me that you are trying the type conversion of char to ascii value or some similar operation of changing the char value to a interger and then decrement it by 1. I got the word decrement to mean -- operator. Is the word correct ? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using extensions:

```
public static int Pred(this int self) => self - 1;
public static int Succ(this int self) => self + 1;
```

Then, this would work:

```
3.Pred() //-> 2
int x = 3;
x.Succ() //-> 4
```

Probably not considered very idiomatic, but still works. Would have to override for other integer types (like `short`). Check if the calls get inlined if you're concerned with performance.

Note: `++` and `--` act as `Inc` and `Dec`, not `Succ` and `Pred`.

Answer (score -1):

You can use ++ or -- operator:

```
3++ = 4
3-- = 2
```

Not sure why you would need it though when you can just do 3+1 or 3-1   :)

Comment: _ It is good to know that I can use operators for that. I just have a little doubt to clarify with you. Is a++ = b and c-- = b?

Comment: You can't write `3++`.  But you can write `a = 3; a++;`.